# Optimal insert/update batch for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, insert

I'm making frequent inserts and updates in large batches from c# code and I need to do it as fast as possible, please help me find all ways to speed up this process.

1. Build command text using `StringBuilder`, separate statements with `;`
2. Don't use `String.Format` or `StringBuilder.AppendFormat`, it's slower then multiple `StringBuilder.Append` calls
3. Reuse `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`
4. Don't use `SqlParameter`s (limits batch size)
5. Use `insert into table values(..),values(..),values(..)` syntax (1000 rows per statement)
6. Use as few indexes and constraints as possible
7. Use simple recovery model if possible
8. ?

Here are questions to help update the list above

1. What is optimal number of statements per command (per one `ExecuteNonQuery()` call)?
2. Is it good to have inserts and updates in the same batch, or it is better to execute them separately?

My data is being received by tcp, so please don't suggest any Bulk Insert commands that involve reading data from file or external table.

Insert/Update statements rate is about 10/3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use table-valued parameters. They can scale really well when using large numbers of rows, and you can get performance that approaches BCP level. I blogged about a way of making that process pretty simple from the C# side [here](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/blog/post/2011/05/21/A-generic-list-for-passing-table-valued-parameters-to-SQL-Server.aspx). Everything else you need to know is on the MSDN site [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx). You will get *far* better performance doing things this way rather than making little tweaks around normal SQL batches.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to do it and be back with results.

Comment: I would also suggest having only one index on the table (a clustered Identity) or possibly leaving it on a heap. If you need other indexes try dropping them before and then recreating them after import.

Comment: Thanks @Gizmo, table is pretty big, 20 columns or so. 
Incoming data flows constantly, and i still will have to run selects on that table so there is no point to drop-recreate indexes.

Comment: @Matt can you say something about performance of creating DataTable vs SqlDataRecords?

Comment: Ok. I tested it myself, DataTable is 14 times slower.

Comment: If you read the blog post I linked to, then go onto Bob B's blog from there and read about the trivial plan thing - that should give you an idea...

Comment: @Matt I was interested it c# execution time

Comment: Well, all done, it needed quite a thought, because building string with `StringBuilder` is obviously faster than generating `SqlDataRecord` for each row. But at the end TVP are much more efficient, in my case in 4-5 times faster and about 5 times less CPU load. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As of SQLServer2008 TableParameters are the way to go. See this article (step four)

http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/05/16/sql-server-high-performance-inserts/

I combined this with parallelizing the insertion process. Think that helped also, but would have to check ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) into a temp table and then use the [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) SQL command to merge the data.

Comment: That definitely might be an option, i just don't see why not to `WriteToServer(DataRow[])` directly to my table? 
Since i'm trying to use table valued params and it needs datarows to be created anyway i will compare performance of this two methods.

Comment: Eh, no, i can't use this because i need updates too. You might suggest to update temp table and MERGE but i don't even need to test that to say it will be slower than TVPs

Comment: How do you know what to insert/update?
If you use MERGE you don't need to get data to check if you need to update, just upload what you got and MERGE.

Comment: That's a good point, but still i think temp tables should be slower